# automation : Script to take a mysqldump into a file named by date/time of backup

Tags: python, automation, backup, mysql

I tried fabric with a '>' in the command string. It always gives out an error code 2. Currently dabbling with subprocess.call, subprocess.check_output and keeping stdout="filesocket". Not working. The only thing that gets written in the file is the USAGE for mysqldump. Using shlex to parse 'mysqldump -uroot -ppassword database table1 table2'

All this because I don't know shell scripting with string variables from the 'date' utility. How do I take the current date and use it to name the backup file in shell script. OR how do I get this thing done in python?

Thanks in advance.

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a custom date out of date using the following syntax.

```
CUSTOM_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")
```

The easiest way to accomplish this is to put a script on the remote end that does 'everything'

```
#!/bin/bash

CUSTOM_DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S")
mysqldump -u admin -p password database table1 table2 >/path/to/backups/mysqldump.${CUSTOM_DATE}.db
```

Answer (score 1):

**"How do I take the current date and use it to name the backup file in shell script. OR how do I get this thing done in python?"**

```
from datetime import datetime

filename = 'mysql_backup_{0:%Y%m%d_%H%M}.sql'.format(datetime.now())

# filename == 'mysql_backup_20120227_0952.sql'
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer from related [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28785570/236732).

In **Microsoft Windows**, run below command in CMD

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pYOURPASSWORD --all-databases > "C:/mysql_backup_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql"
```

Output file will look like,

> mysql_backup_21-02-2015-13_07_18.sql

If you want to automate the backup process, then you can use Windows Task Scheduler, and put above command in .bat file - task scheduler will run the .bat file at specified interval.