# how to add date and time with backupfile name using mysqldump from command prompt and to define the path of backupfile

Tags: mysql

Im using this command for backup from mysqldump

mysqldump -uroot -ptrackerdb) --alldatabases >test.sql

Now i want to add date-time with my backup file like current date and time e.g test_25July2013_13:00

For this i add test_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.sql in file name but it gives error

'Couldn't find table': date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Important Note: you should use correct date format as mentioned below BUT the reason of this error 'Couldn't find table' is that mysql command think that you added table name after database name! so easily surround your file_name with double quotes to get rid of that error. :)

Answer (score 18):

I'm using that:

LINUX

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p <database> | bzip2 -c > <backup>$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.bz2
```

WINDOWS (googled it, because i have been using LIN only)

```
@echo off
cls
echo Date format = %date%
echo dd = %date:~0,2%
echo mm = %date:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~6,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %time%
echo hh = %time:~0,2%
echo mm = %time:~3,2%
echo ss = %time:~6,2%
echo.
echo Timestamp = %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

%mysqldir%\mysqldump -u %mysqluser% -p%mysqlpassword% -h %mysqlhost% -P %mysqlport% --databases --routines --verbose gnucash_shockwave > %BackupDir%\gnucash_shockwave-%timestamp%.sql
```

[here more info](https://superuser.com/questions/512163/using-date-and-times-in-a-batch-file-to-create-a-file-name)

Comment: it also depends if it's Windows or LINUX

Comment: < is unexpected at this time
I am writing : 

mysqldump -uroot -ptrackerdb) --alldatabases | bzip2 -c > <backup>$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.bz2

Comment: command was not useful. it wasn't useful because it is saving the file with my time and my date. i want to save it with current time and date.

Comment: above command saves me a gnucash_shockwave-.sql file with empty date

Comment: Important Note: you should use correct date format as mentioned above BUT the reason of this error 'Couldn't find table' is that mysql command think that you added table name after database name! so easily surround your file_name with double quotes to get rid of that error. :)

Answer (score 4):

In **Microsoft Windows**, run below command in CMD

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pYOURPASSWORD --all-databases > "C:/mysql_backup_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql"
```

Output file will look like,

> mysql_backup_21-02-2015-13_07_18.sql

If you want to automate the backup process, then you can use Windows Task Scheduler, and put above command in .bat file - task scheduler will run the .bat file at specified interval.

Comment: Above command yields me a C:/mysql_backup_.sql file even though the date string is printed on the cmd prompt with an echo. Any hint of what it might be?

Answer (score 2):

> mysqldump -u Database Username  --password=Database password 
>   --all-databases |gzip > /home/username/MySQLDBBK$(date +%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S$*%M*%S).sql.gz

this Cmd is Working.

Comment: Note: /home/username/zip filename .sql.gz

Answer (score 0):

The solution (posted above by Piyush Patel) is the one I used, that actually **works very well**. But I just needed to backup a single database, periodically, with the date and time and I was getting the same error as the OP.
So now I use it this way:(using the quotes "" as suggested above)

```
mysqldump -u root -pusername databasename > "databasename_backup_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql"
```

**Keep in mind** - I run this script from the same folder where the backups are going.
Thanks to all who contributed to this thread.