# How do I fix the error that occurs when I enter the file path and date in mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, dump

How do I fix the error that occurs when I enter the file path and date in mysqldump?

I ran the mysqldump command as follows in cmd:

`set _my_datetime=%date:-=%`

`mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases -pMyPassword > C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\data\backup\%_my_datetime%.sql`

But the result is:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

I wonder how to modify the above command in Windows server environment.

Comment: hi @ringhiosi, did my answer work for your case? Do you need further help from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `%date:-=%` will be evaluated as `Tue 10/19/2021`, and this date separator forward slash `/` conflicts with the path being used in the `mysqldump` command.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>set _my_datetime=%date:-=%

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>echo %_my_datetime%
Tue 10/19/2021
```

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\data\backup\%_my_datetime%.sql
=> Will be: C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\data\backup\Tue 10/19/2021.sql
```

which is an incorrect Windows path syntax and throws a generic syntax exception in your case.

**Solution**
Find a way to format the date with separator as dash `-` or underscore `_` instead.

You can simply use

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases -pMyPassword > "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\data\backup\mysql_backup_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%-%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql"
```

will give a filename pattern: `mysql_backup_10-19-2021-10_08_12.sql`

Date format in Windows command line can be taunting in its way.

*Reference*:
[how to add date and time with backupfile name using mysqldump from command prompt and to define the path of backupfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853838/how-to-add-date-and-time-with-backupfile-name-using-mysqldump-from-command-promp)
[Format date and time in a Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script)